# Using predicate in find_if

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have a struct like this.

```
struct MaxWinPerElementInfo
{
   std::string paytableName;
   std::string elementName;
   long long  elementCredits;
   bool        multiplierRequired;
};
```

I want to find the element that matches the `paytableName`. For that I planned to use `std::find_if` with a predicate function.

I declared the function object within the `struct MaxWinPerElementInfo` as,

```
bool operator() ( const MaxWinPerElementInfo &elementInfo ) const
{
    return paytableName == elementInfo.paytableName;
}
```

Now I tried searching for the element by calling,

`std::find_if( elementInfo.begin(), elementInfo.end(), MaxWinPerElementInfo( paytable));`

where
 `elementInfo` is `std::vector< struct MaxWinPerElementInfo >` and `paytable` is `std::string`.

For this I am getting the error, `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const MaxWinPerElementInfo&’`

I cannot use c++11 since this is a legacy code.

What I am missing here? Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::find_if( elementInfo.begin(), elementInfo.end(), 
    MaxWinPerElementInfo( paytable));
```

You are trying to construct a `MaxWinPerElementInfo` by passing it a string. Do you have a constructor taking a string? I guess not so the compiler tries to call copy constructor which takes a const `MaxWinPerElementInfo` reference. If no constructor taking a single argument is defined, compiler will revert to the only one it knows: Copy contructor.

Since you have a struct and members are public, I would suggest implementing this outside of the class with a functor object.

```
struct MaxWinPerElementInfoPayTablePredicate
{
    MaxWinPerElementInfoPayTablePredicate(const std::string& _paytableName) : 
        paytableName(_paytableName) {}

    bool operator() ( const MaxWinPerElementInfo &elementInfo ) const
    {
        return paytableName == elementInfo.paytableName;
    }

    std::string paytableName;
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
std::find_if( elementInfo.begin(), elementInfo.end(), 
    MaxWinPerElementInfoPayTablePredicate(paytable) );
```

Answer (score 4):

Your class has no conversion constructor that accepts an argument of type std::string. So the compiler issues an error parsing expression

```
MaxWinPerElementInfo( paytable)
```

You could use a lambda expression instead of the functional object. For example

```
std::find_if( elementInfo.begin(), elementInfo.end(), 
              [&] ( const MaxWinPerElementInfo &elementInfo  )
              {
                 return paytableName == elementInfo.paytableName;
              } );
```

If you may not to use lambda expressions then you could define inside the structure a functional object. For example

```
struct MaxWinPerElementInfo
{
   std::string paytableName;
   std::string elementName;
   long long  elementCredits;
   bool        multiplierRequired;

   struct FindByPaytableName
   {
      FindByPaytableName( const std::string &paytableName ) : paytableName( paytableName ) {}
      std::string paytableName;
      bool operator() ( const MaxWinPerElementInfo &elementInfo ) const
      {
          return paytableName == elementInfo.paytableName;
      }
   };
};


std::find_if( elementInfo.begin(), elementInfo.end(), 
              MaxWinPerElementInfo::FindByPaytableName( paytableName ) );
```

Using an inner structure allows you to define several criteria for searching by using various data members of the outer structure.

Comment: Thanks for the example **lambda**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a constructor which takes a string and puts it in paytableName.  Otherwise you cannot create a MaxWinPerElementInfo from a string as you are trying to do within the `find_if()` call.